# Creating text files by open() "w" mode

Tags: python

Where is it documented that "w" mode in open() creates a new file?  I went through all the info https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open, but I didn't find anything about why this "w" creates a new text file.

Comment: You could know this with some info on how files work, but in this case the relevant text is "Truncate the file *if* it already exists." which implies that there is an option the file does not yet exist, and the description for `x` which mentions that it will, unlike `w`, fail if the file exists, implying they behave the same if the file does not exist

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're using cpython, it internally uses C standard library function fopen().
http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/

```
 ``w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
         The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

 ``w+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
         the beginning of the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `open()`, the default mode is `r` which is `read-only`.

You can read more about different modes [here](https://stackabuse.com/file-handling-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20access%20modes%20available%20for,the%20beginning%20of%20the%20file.).